# Output list as "x1, x2, ... 'and xN'"

Tags: python, list

I can do this

```
fruits=['mango','fig','apple']

for fruit in fruits:
    print (fruit , end=" ")
```

OUTPUT:

```
mango fig apple
```

---

How to rewrite this using a loop?

```
fruits=['mango','fig','apple']

print(f"i have {fruits[0]},{fruits[1]} and {fruits[2]}")
```

expectation :

```
i have mango,fig and apple
```

Comment: Will this work? `print(f'i have {" ".join(f for f in fruits)}')`

Comment: @Priya last before item should have `and` before...Even I got same idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want a loop for this, but you could do:

```
parts = ['i have ', ',', ' and ']
fruits=['mango','fig','apple']
for part, fruit in zip(parts, fruits):
   print(part+fruit, end="")
print()
```

This is not by any means a thing you'd do, but I guess it's a way to learn about zips.

Comment: What is `parts`? Where is `and` here?

Comment: Sorry, paste failure!

Comment: Doesn't seem scalable... What if there is a 4th fruit added?

Comment: Of course it's not scalable! :) Like I say, it's not how I'd do it - but it does meet the requirements of the question, which was to produce the required output using a loop.

Comment: `str.join` uses an implicit loop :)

Comment: well, by that logic, the evaluation of a series of python instructions is also an implicit loop :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use with loop,

```
print('I have', end=" ")
for idx, i in enumerate(fruits):
    if idx == len(fruits) - 1:
        print(f"and {i}", end=" ")    
    else:
        print(i, end=", ")
# I have mango, fig, and apple
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
print(f"i have {', '.join(fruits[:-1])} and {fruits[-1]}")
```

This will work for any size list that you want comma-separated except for the last item where you want an 'and'.

If you have to use a loop, for some reason (assuming this is homework and you have to keep it simple) then you could do something like:

```
output_msg = "I have"
for i, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
    if i == 0:
        output_msg += f" {fruit}"
    elif i == len(fruits): 
         output_msg += f" and {fruit}"
    else:
         output_msg += f",{fruit}"
print(output_msg)
```

Comment: question specifically asks for the solution to use a loop. (I don't know why, but that's what it asks for)

Comment: Makes sense. Must be homework. I have updated.

Answer (score 1):

Slice the string

```
>>> fruits=['mango','fig','apple']
>>> print('I have ' + ', '.join(fruits[:-1]) + ' and ' + fruits[-1])
I have mango, fig and apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, don't use in production code:

```py
fruits = ["mango", "fig", "apple"]

for f, s in zip(
    fruits, [*[","] * (len(fruits) - 2), " and ", "\n"][-len(fruits) :]
):
    print(f, end=s)
```

Prints:

```
mango,fig and apple
```